# Quarto - Pass dataframe as parameter and run from Python script

Tags: python, r-markdown, quarto

Similar to RMarkdown, can we pass dataframe as a parameter?

[How can I pass variables into an R markdown .Rmd file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18929782/how-can-i-pass-variables-into-an-r-markdown-rmd-file)

Also, can we trigger the Quarto code from a Python script? Currently doing this
`os.system("quarto render plot_demo.qmd -P alpha:0.1 -P beta:0.2")`

In R/RMarkdown, I could do this from an R Script

```
rmarkdown::render("doc.Rmd", params=list(a=a,b=b,c=c), output_dir = <output_dir>, output_file=<output_file>)
```

where parameter such as `a` could be a dataframe too.

Answer (score 0):

In R, there is a quarto package that has the quarto_render() function. It is similar to the rmarkdown::render() function but uses the execute_params argument to pass data in to the document.

[quarto package - quarto_render()](https://quarto-dev.github.io/quarto-r/reference/quarto_render.html)